# How to get data from a JSON file using Azure functions and C# which is in Blob storage and Storing JSON data as columns in Azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

How to get data from a JSON file (filename.json) using Azure functions and C# which is in Blob storage and Storing JSON data as columns in Azure table storage. My function app will be triggered when a json file has been placed in the path. So basically, there will be a JSON file with multiple records (tuple) in Blob Storage of ADLS Gen2 and I have to upload that to Table storage.

I have barely ever written code in C# before, any help with an elaborate description and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

I am also fairly new to Azure, so if anyone has a better suggestion on how to achieve what I am trying to do (that is maybe using a different trigger or different binders), I would gladly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a function with Azure [Blob storage trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp) and output binding of [azure table storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-output?tabs=in-process%2Cstorage-extension&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

uploading a file in your blob storage will trigger your function and you can then do any work needed to parse your json and push it to the table.

you can have a look at the links, get your blob trigger working and firing your function, then add to your function to include the output binding.

if you get stuck you can always update your question with the code thats giving you an issue.

one more link for [getting started with c# functions in azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?tabs=in-process).